# pip installed Pyinstaller in global site-packages instead of venv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I've created virtual environment using following command:

```
py -m venv pygui
```

Then I've activated it in CMD prompt:

```
cd pygui/Scripts
activate.bat
```

However when I've tried to install new libraries with pip I don't see it in the list.

```
pip install pyinstaller
pip list
```

The only library I can see is:
pip     23.2.1
[image]

Even if I'm trying to install it outside the environment, as:

```
py -m pip install pyinstaller --upgrade
```

I'm not able to call it, as I get the following error:
[image: 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.]

I've checked "path" in environment variables and looks correct to me.

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Comment: None of the directories on your path look related to your virtual environment. You don't appear to be using the `pip` associated with the virtual environment.

Comment: If you are using Powershell/Windows Terminal use `activate.ps1`. Running `pip -V` should return something like `...\pygui\Lib\site-packages\pip`, not the main install.

Comment: @ivvija, yes, the output is:
...pygui\pygui\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps fixed the issue:

**[Set-ExecutionPolicy]** Based on answer provided by Rahul Chauhan in [virtualenv activate does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194427/virtualenv-activate-does-not-work), update the execution policy.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUs
```

**[Update pip.ini]** Then according to Uralbi in [pip installing in global site-packages instead of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv), update content in "pip.ini" in the following directory:  "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini".

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org
default-timeout = 60
respect-virtualenv = true
download-cache = /tmp
log-file = /tmp/pip-log.txt
```

**[.venv]** Finally create .venv, activate it and convert .py to .exe.

```
python -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
pip install -r requirements.txt
python -m PyInstaller --onefile -w 'main.py'
```

**[pyinstaller error]**: Note in order to avoid this [*win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error when using pyinstaller in VS Code - Possible Virus/Trojan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239487/win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-when-using-pyinstaller-in-vs-code-possib) error:

```
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 143, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    hdst = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(dstpath, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 208, in BeginUpdateResource
    with _pywin32error():
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
**win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (225, 'BeginUpdateResourceW', 'Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.')**
```

You can use older release (5.13.2) of PyInstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller==5.13.2
```

If anyone else have alternative or better solutions, please let me know.