Jupyter Notebook running in a local pyenv does not see PIP installed packages
I am trying to use python, pyenv, and 'jupyter' notebooks on my MacBook.
Everything seems configured to use my pyenv properly, but when I run the Jupyter notebook, it can't find some packages I installed with pip. They are confirmed as installed as they show up in the pip list command.
I confirmed that pyenv is set up properly and that everything is running within the same local virtual environment, they all are running from the same virtual 'bin' directory ~//.venv/bin
All of that looks good, but when I launch the Jupyter notebook from the command line within that local pyenv, it doesn't see my additional installed PIP packages.
I looked at other answers to a similar problem, but they did not help.

Hi Mark,
I had similar issue, for me it was resolved in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820213/pip-installed-pyinstaller-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-venv/77832747#77832747

I found everything works fine if I configure a pyenv at the shell level. I'll checkout your what you shared.

So, I suspect your jupyteris installed in another environment, or the same one? In your notebook, what does import sys; print(sys.executable) give you?

It's generally recommended to install Jupyter inside your virtual environment to ensure it has access to all the packages installed within that environment. Activate your virtual environment and install Jupyter using pip:
In the shell terminal try below:

$ source ~/.venv/bin/activate
$ pip install jupyter

